# Why 0 == CGFLOAT_MIN is false?

Tags: objective-c

Why 0 is not equal CGLOAT_MIN when compare directly

My Code

```
float minVar = CGFLOAT_MIN;

printf("CGFLOAT_MIN = %f\n\n", CGFLOAT_MIN);
printf("0 == CGFLOAT_MIN  \t%s\n", (0) == CGFLOAT_MIN ? "true" : "false");
printf("0 == minVar       \t%s\n", (0) == minVar ? "true" : "false");
printf("0 == 0.000000     \t%s\n", (0) == 0.000000 ? "true" : "false");
```

The Output is

```
CGFLOAT_MIN = 0.000000

0 == CGFLOAT_MIN    false
0 == minVar         true
0 == 0.000000       true
```

Comment: Documentation: "For 32-bit code, this value is `1.17549435e-38F`. For 64-bit code, it is `2.2250738585072014e-308`."

Comment: you should rarely compare floating point values exactly; use an epsilon.

Answer (score 4):

Because `CGFLOAT_MIN` is **not** equal to 0. It's the smallest representable positive non-zero value that `CGFloat` can hold.

```
printf("CGFLOAT_MIN = %f\n\n", CGFLOAT_MIN);
```

This prints `0.000000` because the `%f` specifier defaults to rounding to 6 decimal places. `CGFLOAT_MIN` gets rounded down to zero at that relatively coarse level of precision.

```
float minVar = CGFLOAT_MIN;
// ...
printf("0 == minVar       \t%s\n", (0) == minVar ? "true" : "false");
```

This prints true because, when building for 64-bit, `CGFloat` is equivalent to `double`, not `float`. `float` has less precision; it can't properly represent the value of `CGFLOAT_MIN`. So, again, the conversion to `float` rounds it down to 0. So, `minVar` is equal to 0, even though `CGFLOAT_MIN` is not.